# Where does iTunes Match store songs on my iDevice?

Tags: ios, itunes-match

I know in a regular situation (without iTunes Match), the music is stored in `/User/Media/iTunes_Control/Music`. However, all of my `FXX` folders are empty. Does iTunes Match cache files in a different location than the regular iOS iPod storage place?

I am running iOS 5.0.1 on iPhone 4S.

Edit: I deleted all my `FXX` folders, and my entire `Music` folder and my music still plays. Does anyone have an idea how I can find where these songs, and/ or a database file are downloaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

look at

```
/var/mobile/Media/Purchases/
```